# EXT JS : Can't validate form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, extjs

I started learning EXT JS a few days ago, and I'm having issues validating the following form. I'm currently just running tests on the "password" field. The submit button is always active, and when I try to check if the form is valid, well it seems to be considered as such.

```
    var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
            layout: 'vbox',
            width: 300,
            height: 100,
            defaults: {
                labelStyle: 'padding:7 0 0 25;',
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'field',
                name: 'Username',
                fieldLabel: 'Username',
                value: 'Your Username',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'field',
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                name: 'Password',
                value: '',
                inputType: 'password',
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength:5,
                 /*                 validator : function(){
                alert('ttt');
                    return false;
                },
                validateOnChange: true*/
                listeners:{
                    focus : function(){
                        alert(this.isValid());  // Always shows "true"
                    }
                }
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Submit',
                margin: '0 100 0 0',
                formBind: true,
                handler: function(){
                    alert('submitted');
                }
            }]
        });
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after one and a half hour of debugging, I found that the issue was just the xtype : it should be set to "textfield" instead of "field".